# Rails 4: ActionView::MissingTemplate even though view exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following routes:

```
  resource :checkout, only: [:show, :create] do
    scope module: :checkouts do
      resource :guest, only: [:create]
      resource :confirmation, only: [:show]
    end
  end
```

But when I hit the `checkout/confirmation` route, I get the error `Missing template checkouts/confirmations/show` even though I have a `HAML` file located at `app/views/checkouts/confirmations/show.haml`.

If I grep the routes, looking for confirmation, this is what I get:

```
 checkout_confirmation GET    /checkout/confirmation(.:format)                                          checkouts/confirmations#show
```

I'm completely stumped. In my `show` method if I render JSON, it works, but something with the view file itself rails isn't liking.

I am using Rails 4

Comment: I guess your view needs to be` app/views/checkout/confirmation/show.haml` since you are using `resource`  - singular. Try creating this path and  see how it goes.

Comment: Tried that and no dice :( I've tried every combination I can think of and nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

change the file name to `show.html.haml`